# clang: error: no input files, React Native 0.59.9 YGFloatOptional.cpp file not found, react native ios error

Tags: react-native-ios

I updated react-native version to the latest one in my existing project, now my ios app is not running. It gives me an error::

> no such file or directory:
> '/path-to-project-folder/myproject/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGFloatOptional.cpp'
>
> clang: error: no input files

I am using React Native 0.59.9 version.

Comment: any luck with this?  i'm having the same issue